# Excel VBA - Does a range possess/contain a date

Tags: vba, excel, date, find, range

I am searching for a solution to check whether a certain range (in my case a whole row) contains any date values. Therefore the find etc. methods where only a certain date is asked for is not in my interest.

I already tried the `IsDate(Cells(x, y).Value)` or `IsDate(Range("xy"))` which works fine for only one cell to check, but unfortunately it does not work for more than only one cell.

I also tried the following:

```
If IsDate(Sheets("test").Range(Cells(7, 2), Cells(7, 3)).Value) Then
    MsgBox ("works")
End If
```

and both cells were dates and also worked with the `IsDate` by only checking their single cell.

Could somebody help me with this problem? 
How to check whether a whole row contains any date value? 
And please try it without for looping through each cell.

Comment: Why avoid looping?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
For Each cell In Range("A1:D3")
       If IsDate(cell.Value) Then MsgBox cell.Value 
next
```

edit: sorry I not read without looping... but maybe somebody use my method

Answer (score 0):

You can't check a whole range to see if it contains a date, it's not possible, it has to be done on a cell by cell basis, but it can be reduced by dropping out at the first positive answer.

Consider the below cells: -

```
' |A      |B              |C
'1|This   |10/June/2016   |Date is 10/06/16
```

To try and process them in one go would be to ask is `This10/June/2016Date is 10/06/16` a date? the answer is no.

A1 is not a date

B1 is a date

C1 is not a date (it contains a date but is considered a string as it has content that is not a date as well)

We must check them one by one to isolate what we are checking.

I am assuming from your question, you don't need any further information than 'yes there is a date in this range' (i.e. you don't need to know where). This can only be achieved with a loop: -

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim WkSht           As Worksheet
Dim Rng             As Range
Dim Cl              As Range
Dim BlnContainsDate As Boolean

'Connect to worksheet
Set WkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Define a range to check
    Set Rng = WkSht.Range("A2:J2")

        'Check each cell
        For Each Cl In Rng.Cells

            'Its there is a date in any of them, flag it and stop checking
            If IsDate(Cl.Value) Then
                BlnContainsDate = True
                Exit For
            End If

        Next
    Set Rng = Nothing
Set WkSht = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you want it to not look like a loop you could call it like a sub procedure and get a result back: -

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim WkSht           As Worksheet

'Connect to worksheet
Set WkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Send a range to be checked
    Debug.Print ContainsADate(WkSht.Range("A2:J2"))

Set WkSht = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function ContainsADate(ByVal Rng As Range) As Boolean

'Check each cell we were passed
For Each Cl In Rng.Cells

    'Its there is a date in any of them, flag it and stop checking
    If IsDate(Cl.Value) Then
        ContainsADate = True
        Exit For
    End If

Next

End Function
```